# Effect of magnetic field on stationary charge

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a long infinite current carrying wire in N-S direction.

Consider a charge +q at a distance of r from wire.

Clearly, Lorentz force on charge is 0.

But, their is a relative motion between charge and current in wire.

Can't this cause Lorentz force?

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic field will not apply any force on the charge if the charge does not have a velocity (or a component of velocity)that's perpendicular to its own direction. 
A magnet is basically a collection of current carrying loops. Since current is basically movement of electrons, electroSTATIC force has nothing to do with it. 
A current carrying loop will attract another current carrying loop. Not any random charge that too at rest.

Comment: But, isn't there a magnetic field, which implies an electric field, which should effect charge.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Why do you say a static magnetic field implies an electric field?

Comment: @ragnar because magnetic fields are basically created by motion of electrons.A part of electric field due to length contraction is magnetic field.

Comment: Sure, electrons produce an electric field, but so do the positively charged atomic nuclei to which they are bound. At distances beyond the nanometer scale, these two fields cancel more or less exactly.

Comment: @ragnar Did you read next line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @anubhav the field due to the charges in a neutral bulk substance on nearby charges is negligible as ragnar said. Every object has moving electrons in orbitals in it. But you don't see them attracting/repelling charged particles just like that. It's the same with the bar magnet. If the charged particle has no velocity, no interaction with magnet.

Comment: Electrons in magnet move in their orbitals and so have relative velocity. Which must cause force oin charge particle.

Answer (score 0):

the length contraction will happen but we must consider the fact that this is happening because a frame is moving at the same speed as the current making charge particles. However at the same time we can easily observe that the wire in which current is there is moving backwards at the same speed or the positive charged atoms or regions are moving backward so thereby again constituting the same current which in turn gives the same magnetic field that's observed by the rest frame which might feel length contraction..so in both frame of references there shouldn't be any electric field.

Comment: besides, this fact can also be made clear by ruminating about maxwell's equations. If the magnetic field is time independent then curl of electric field is zero which leads to two possibilities ; first either the electric field should be zero or it should be conservative but if i move ahead with later output, we shall find again through maxwell's(oliver heavside) equations that this will lead to magnetic field which has 0 curl and that's impossible    as long as i shun dirac's magnetic monoploes equation

Comment: Too tough, can you draw some picture etc, or give some equations that apply. It shall help me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Nowhere in the statement of the question do you explicitly state that the current carrying wire is uncharged, but since that is the usual assumption I will assume that is what was intended.

Then the analysis of the force on the charge is clear. $F= q(E+v\times B)$. The first term is 0 because the wire is uncharged, and the second term is also 0 because the charge is stationary. Therefore the Lorentz force is unambiguously 0.

The exact motion of the moving charge carriers is not directly relevant (a large number of slow charges makes the same current as a small number of fast charges). The relevant question is whether or not the wire is charged in the rest frame and what current it carries.

Comment: -1 because it is not answer I want,,, well I like part when you say whether a current carrying neutral wire is charged or not? ..The next point I will ponder...